# What is the best and optimized way to extract data from XML multiple times?

Tags: java, performance, xml-parsing, string-parsing

In our application we had a requirement to retrieve data from `XML` multiple times. We make a service call, get data in `xml` format and save in memory. Later as we need to retrieve data using either element name or attribute name multiple times and this makes to parse `xml` each and every time which is not a good way to go.

We have limitation of only saving as String in memory and also cannot use Spring or any framework so either we can save as `xml` or convert String into some format and parse that String. These are the options I could think off:

1. Parse XML every time we need to retrieve value.
2. Extract required data from XML using parser and save it as map in String format and parse map data using custom code.
3. Convert big XML to small XML and parse that small XML every time.
4. String split functions.

Appreciate if any one can suggest fast way to retrieve data from String

Comment: have you tried regex ? can you give an example for xml what you need to extract from it ?

Comment: We have complex XMLs which can be of more than 1000 lines and here is sample xml. <person id="123456"><firstname>abcd</firstname><lastname>cdef<lastname></person>. For one case we need to extract firstname value and in another case we need to extract id.

Comment: Why is there a constraint on saving the data as String? Might it also be byte[]?

Answer (score 1):

Transform your large dataset to a small dataset. Use an efficient serializer/parser. Do pull parsing and serialization, avoid object bindings (DOM / annotated objects).

Stop parsing when you have what you want, if possible. Possibly arrange your data, i.e. sort, to achieve this.

JSON or [XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/aalto-xml) is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am the author of vtd-xml, I must acknowledge that my point of view may be biased. But VTD-XML is ideal for your use case.

Let me explain more:

*First parsing will not be a big problem as with DOM with VTD-XML.

- You can also choose to persist parsed result with vtd-xml's built-in indexing. Basically, if you can reuse the same xml without parsing it more than once ... it is very handy for this... just load the .vxl file into memory. VTD-XML has 2 parts, the XML (literal XML that is human readable). The other is the binary index part as the output of the parsing.
- Since VTD-XML uses far less memory than DOM. Your point #3 may become unnecessary.
- Also vtd-xml's indexing strucuture is super easy to understand. It can be written on the back of a match box.
- Also vtd-xml is perfect for Big xml splitting if you understand the underlying principle of it...

Let me know if you got any question.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the impression I'm getting: You need to store the serialized contents of an XML file in a variable of type String, and you need the fastest way to do this.

Assuming that arrays or linked lists of strings are not allowed, you could convert the XML into JSON, which is considerably faster to parse, easier to cache, and smaller in size than XML or any other serialization format. The resulting JSON would then be minified and stored in a string.

For example, the XML

```
 <data>
    <list>
        <item>Item A</item>
        <item>Item B</item>
    </list>
</data>
```

could become

```
{"data":{"list":{"item":["a","b"]}}}
```

Note how much smaller that is than the XML, especially considering the fact that there are only opening "tags" and not closing ones, as are needed in XML. A string storing the transformed JSON data would take up less memory (and the amount of data saved would become more apparent with larger data sets) and be considerably faster to parse. Additionally, JSON is the standard for online data transfers and is outperforming XML in many areas, especially in larger datasets or where there is a considerable level of complexity in the objects being stored.

Here is some more reading on this topic:

**JSON vs XML with a Web-oriented point of view**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp

**"JSON: The Fat-Free Alternative to XML"**

http://www.json.org/xml.html

**An objective comparison between JSON and XML**

https://www.sitepoint.com/json-vs-xml/

Hope I helped! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**
I just saw your comment on your question that your XML stores extremely large data sets. In this case, I would not recommend using any sort of serialization but rather storing the data in a database (for what you need, I think something like MongoDB would work the best, given its unstructured approach and suitability for large datasets) and extracting only the records you currently need into a smaller string of JSON, XML, or even an array of classes in whichever language you use.

Comment: Thank you Plato. So you recommend converting to JSON format and parse JSON String rather than xml? Also we are invoking service call to get data and again storing data in DB is not a option for us.

Comment: @Mr9 Yes, I would definitely recommend converting to JSON format and parsing as a JSON string over parsing straight XML.